# php cant load internal PDO class

Tags: php, pdo

```
private function _connect(){
    try {
                $this->con = new PDO(''.$this->dbdriver.':host='.$this->dbhost.';dbname='.$this->dbname.'', $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
                $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
                $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
                return TRUE;
            }   catch (PDOException $e){    
                $reg = registry::_getInstance();
                $reg->offsetSet('R_errors', $reg->offsetGet('R_errors').'</br>'.$e->getMessage());return false;
            }               
    }
```

I am using the above code to connect to the database but am getting the following errors:
**Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class PDO could not be loaded in /home/tahidihomes/public_html/lib/core/pdo_mysql.core.php on line 72**

What might be the problem?

Comment: I'd say you haven't installed PDO. Have you?

Comment: Are you namespacing?

Comment: Please check PDO installed. Try phpinfo() to find this.

Comment: the PDO modules are installed, did a phpinfo() and its there! I dont know whats the problem!  Here's the link to my page.[page](http://tahidihomes.com)

Comment: on my local host its working

Answer (score 0):

Retry after PDO installation. If you get same error try again with the below code in top of index page

```html
spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .class.php');
spl_autoload_register();
```